# Setting the EVPN VXLAN Interconnect ESI for Data Center Interconnect (Seamless EVPN VXLAN Stitching)

Tags: ethernet, juniper, vxlan, evpn, data-center

With reference to Juniper Networks , when implementing data center interconnect (DCI) using seamless EVPN VXLAN stitching , *why do we have to define iESI (interconnect ESI) to stitch VXLAN VNI from Border LEAF-1 (located in DC1) to Border LEAF-2 (located in DC2)?*

The following snippet is taken from Juniper Day one book 'seamless EVPN VXLAN Tunnel stitching for DC and DCI'

[image]

```
For EVPN Type 2 routes it specifies to use iESI to stretch the EVPN Type 2 from DC1 to DC2 but doesnot explain the reason ? What is the potential issue if the iESI is not defined on Border LEAFs?
```

Also when it comes to EVPN Type 5 routes stretching from DC1 to DC2 then iESI is not needed here.

Will be grateful if someone explain this !!